# Samsung S4 Google Sync Settings Problems

Tags: contacts, settings, sync, gmail, menu

When I am in settings, Accounts, Google, myemail@gmail.com, I see "Sync turned off. I select it and get a list of things I can sync. I can hit each and sync it, but there are no check boxes to auto sync certain features, I have limited data and don't want to sync all continuously, not that I can see how to anyway. A few minutes ago, at the bottom I could choose 'Sync All', now that option is gone, this whole screen makes no sense to me, basically, I always want to sync contacts, gmail and Chrome settings, nothing else, anyone know how? Always in awe of how bad menu designs/UIs (don't) work.
Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

I am using S4 Kitkat though, however I was in the same situation where I needed to enable Sync for selective Providers like Google mail, Calendar, Contacts (not Google Games, Google Books etc).
I ended up using the [Synker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.afterhoursdevelopers.android.synker&hl=en) App (Paid) to achieve those. However, not sure if it works equally well in Lollipop!